# Message Boxes in MVVM-patterned application

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, messagebox, user-experience

My application uses MVVM pattern in UI design.

At application start-up a splash screen appears and the logic begins to execute. A hearbeat class instance, that is created by IoC container, polls the plugin directory for plugin dlls at this point.

In case the directory does not exist or is empty, I am considering that the installation is corrupted and an application need to be re-installed.

At this point very logical (but not very MVVM) would be to just show user a MessageBox with this info and close an application.

What more elegant solution would you recommend?

One that comes to my mind, is to bubble the ResourceNotFound exception to ViewModel instance of a splash screen and notify the used via splash screen. Would this create a better user experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would use a IMessageBoxservice to show the error and then close the app. i dont think that the "info" splashscreen is a better user experience when handling an error.

Answer (score 0):

In such situations I create base view and base view model with properties IsMsg and MsgText.